# How i can develop a model for categorical data with different parameters?

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, ordinal-data

I would like to develop a model on human attitude about the conflict and I have few categorical parameters such as sites, occupations, age etc.
I already used the chi-square test for identifying the significant difference between the sites.

Comment: I think we are going to need some more detail here for anyone to be able to answer this.

Comment: Yup. I'm with mdewey that more information is needed. For instance, what is the source for your data? A survey? Next, what does 'human attitude about conflict' mean? Also, how is it scaled? Is it some kind of rating scale? If so, how is it scaled, e.g., is it unbounded? Bounded and continuous? Ordinal? Etc. Also, how many sites and/or occupations are there? A few? Many? Are there any 'structural zeros' (cells with no observed values or frequencies) in their cross-classification? And so on...please clarify.

Comment: Mdewey and Djohnson, its my bad. This data based on social survey. The attitude on carnivore basically categorized into good, Neutral and Bad.

Comment: like to make a model, Attitude on wildlife~site+occupation+gender+age+Crop damage+human attack+livestock depredation. I already check the chi-square test and correlation test for all variables. Few variables correlated with sites occupation, crop damage, gender.

Comment: SItes =2, Occupation = Famer & nonFarmer, Age= in group, Crop damage, livestock attack or human attack = yes/No,